# ProductName in Windows registry, it is localized for different languages?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry, windows-10

I'm attempting to detect the difference between Windows 7, Windows 8/Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 in my C# application. I'm attempting to determine this by using

```
 HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\ProductName
```

as I can check whether this value contains "Windows 7", "Windows 8", or "Windows 10" reliably.

**My question:** is the ProductName registry value localized when Windows is using a different language pack? Will this reliably return the above values in English, or does it change based on OS language?

Before I get hammered for not using other methods of determining the operating system that everyone likes to recommend... using [OSVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx) is out since it does not always return the correct values. Additionally, [GetVersion and GetVersionEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) are also not an option since they are not recommended after Windows 8.1, they misidentify Windows 10 as Windows 8. The recommended [Version Helper functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx) that are suppose to replace those methods are not available in C#. If anyone knows of another reliable way to determine the difference between those operating systems, please let me know.

Comment: For the usual OsVersion property, the recent version numbers are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: First link doesn't include anything newer than Windows XP. Second link is something I already linked in my question and mentioned why it won't work for my case.

Comment: `GetVersion()` is the way to go :D

Comment: Ok, my link was indirectly refered inside your first link. Except for compatibility modes, in what case is "OsVersion"  incorrect ?

Comment: Windows 10 can report an incorrect major and minor version depending on how your application is manifested.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 企业版(Enterprise) in Chinese:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName = Windows 10 Enterprise
```

which suggests the value is not localized.